how to protect postfix mail from gmail spam
I am experiencing an issue with the BDIX (Local Bangladeshi server) server.
I have set up a mail server on the local BDIX server using postfix with aapanel.
I have configured SPF, DKIM, and DMARC in my DNS, but the problem is that the emails are going to spam. The same configuration worked well on Contabo VPS, and the emails were not marked as spam.
However, when I send emails from the BDIX server, they end up in the spam folder. I am unsure about the cause of the problem. I have added the domain to the postmaster of Gmail more than 24 hours ago, but I haven't received any feedback yet. I have checked my IP on mxtoolbox, and it is not blacklisted. When I used mail-tester, my emails received a score of 10/10.
My domain is: team71.link
My ip: 103.240.5.26
Jun 19 08:08:47 srv postfix/smtpd[280631]: 36688426A6: client=localhost[::1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=help@team71.link
Jun 19 08:08:47 srv postfix/cleanup[282407]: 36688426A6: message-id=<20240619060847.36688426A6@srv.team71.link>
Jun 19 08:08:47 srv postfix/qmgr[176052]: 36688426A6: from=<help@team71.link>, size=793, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 19 08:08:47 srv postfix/smtpd[280631]: disconnect from localhost[::1] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 commands=5
Jun 19 08:08:49 srv postfix/smtp[282408]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 19 08:08:51 srv postfix/smtp[282408]: 36688426A6: to=<orbaic.tomal@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.27]:25, delay=4.4, delays=0.59/0.03/2.7/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1718777331 d9443c01a7336-1f9b31fd806si4201455ad.341 - gsmtp)
Jun 19 08:08:51 srv postfix/qmgr[176052]: 36688426A6: removed


@NikitaKipriyanov, I have tryed but not solved

OK. At a first glance, DNS seems to look correct and myhostname seem to agree, although I can't check your DKIM because I don't know the selector. There is include:_spf.google.com in your SPF; it's not an error and shouldn't do harm, but are you sending mails from this domain via gmail too? Why are you using self-signed certificate? You have a public DNS name, you can obtain Let's Encrypt certificate for use in Postfix. Finally, what does your mail look like, and what appears in your logs when the mail gets delivered? Is it being rejected or is it delivered but put into spam folder?

@NikitaKipriyanov Brother I have update the post. There I have add the postfix response also

Your message was delivered. At this point, you have to refine the contents of the message for Gmail to not consider it a spam, and wait until you gain a reputation. We can't help with that, except suggesting whatever you see under the link.
